# What exactly does Java's ReentrantLock acquire a lock on?

Tags: java, locking

When using Java's ReentrantLock, what object(s) does it actually lock? Is it the objects used in the try block, or the whole object/class in which ReentrantLock is being used.

Thanks.

Comment: `Lock` is merely an interface, so the thing it locks on is implementation-dependent.

Comment: You're right, I meant ReentrantLock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are kind of misunderstanding how a "lock" (any lock) in java works (the default synchronized behavior somewhat confuses that).  Synchronizing on an object does not "lock" that object.  it only locks against other calls which are synchronized on the same object.  Likewise, a ReentrantLock does not "lock" an object, it only locks against other lock calls on the same ReentrantLock.

Comment: But when you use synchronized in a block, it prevents lock being made on whatever variable was put in the (), correct?

Comment: @sepehr78: synchronized prevents threads from acquiring a lock that is currently taken, so a thread that is calling the synchronized block/method can't progress until it can acquire the lock. that is all synchronized does.

Comment: What does that mean? If I do synchronized( obj) {} does that not mean that obj is locked in the following code block?

Comment: no, it does not mean "obj" is locked.  an object can't be locked.  it means that any other thread which attempts to do "synchronized(obj)" will block.

Comment: @jtahlborn , when I do `synchronized(obj)`  i can call `wait` on the `obj`, but when I use the reentrant lock, where can I find this object on which I can call `wait`.

Comment: @Turtle - you create a `Condition` instance from the `Lock` and then you can do the standard wait/notify actions using that object.

Comment: @jtahlborn yes I know about the `Condition` pattern, I just want to know if there is any object on which I can call `wait` without the `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner` exception getting thrown.